# Как провести линию от одного объекта к другому в Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Имеется Spriterenderer от которого требуется провести линию к Image, расположенному в Canvas. Начало линии в Spriterenderer (1 вершина), конец в Image (2 вершина).

Comment: канва естественно screen space?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, конечно. Однако проблема уже решилась

Comment: Тогда оформите самоответ (это лучше, чем второй вариант), либо удалите вопрос за неимением в нем смысла.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public LineRenderer line = FindObjectOfType<LineRenderer>();
Vector3 vec1 = new Vector3(0,0,0);
Vector3 vec2 = new Vector3(1,1,1);//координаты точек
line.setPosition(0, vec1)//0-начальная точка линии
line.setPosition(1, vec2)//1-конечная точка линии
```